# How to get a specific content control using contentControls.getItem?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-contentcontrol

I'm trying to pick up a content control from a document using its position. `ccs.getFirstOrNullObject();` works, but I don't want the first content control. `ccs.getItem(0);` (or any integer value) returns the error:

> ItemNotFound: We couldn’t find the item you requested. Check the
>   OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo for more information.

How can I specify a particular content control by its position in the document?

Code from script lab:

```
async function
    getAdjacentRange() {
    await Word.run(async (context) => {
        var ccs = context.document.contentControls;
        ccs.load("items");
        await context.sync();
        console.log("Nr cc: " + ccs.items.length);
        //works:
        //let cc = ccs.getFirstOrNullObject();
        //doesn't work:
        let cc = ccs.getItem(0);

        let ccRange = cc.getRange("Start");
        let ccParas = ccRange.paragraphs; cc.load("text,range,paragraphs");
        let ccPara = ccParas.getFirst();
        ccParas.load("items")
        let paraRange = ccPara.getRange("Start");
        let rng = paraRange.expandTo(ccRange);
        let em = [" "];
        console.log(em.length.toString());
        let words = rng.getTextRanges(em, true);
        words.load("items");
        await context.sync();
        let nrWords = words.items.length;
        let lastWord = words.items[nrWords - 1];
        let wordBeforeCC = words.getFirst();
        wordBeforeCC.load("text");
        await context.sync();
        console.log(cc.text + "/" + wordBeforeCC.text + "nr Words: " + nrWords + "last word: " + lastWord.text);
})
    }
```

Comment: I can reproduce. I suspect a bug in ContentControlCollection.getItem(). If you don't get an answer in a few days, consider raising an issue on this repo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets not confuse `getItem()` vs. `getItemAt()` methods.  `getItem()` works with IDs, while `getItemAt()` with position.

Given that CCs can be in header/footer and other subdocument, inferring order can be challenging and hence there is no `getItemAt()` method in the cc collection.

That been said, the items array has the content controls in reading order, so `items[0]` gives you the first content control, `items[n - 1]` the last one (assuming `N` ccs in the document).

And yes, you need to load them all.

Here is an example on how to access the 3rd content control in the doc:

```js
await Word.run(async (context) => {
    let ccs = context.document.contentControls;
    ccs.load();
    await context.sync();
    //assuming there are more then 2 
    if(ccs.items.length >= 2)
        console.log(ccs.items[2].text);
});
```

Finally, I recommend you to use the other methods to get access to CCs.

I.e. `contentControls.getById`, `contentControls.getByName()` and `getByTag()`.

Comment: Thanks for the info about `items` - I thought I tried that, but got an error. Where is the fact that `getItem` works with IDs, generally? I haven't seen that in the documentation. For `contentControls` the info for `getIndex` states: "Gets a content control by its index in the collection." And gives the index value as "number"; in the COM object model the ID is typed as a String...

Comment: probably that's a documentation error... you should not get an error on the items.. that's the way to access ccs or the other mentioned ones.

Comment: and yes, in Office.js getItem works with either Ids or names. getItemAt with indexed/position of objects.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, Juan :-) I've submitted documenation feedback. The error with `items` was probably a syntax error on my part - on seeing `getItem` I didn't try further with it.